# Reference Private Property in Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

Is it possible to reference a private property in a lambda expression?  Or only public properties?

For example. say my private property is named InnerCollection, the line of code would be:

```
x => x.InnerCollection
```

Is there a way to achieve this somehow - without using reflection etc.?

Using .NET 4.0.

Thanks.

Chris

Comment: "Private Property" means you can't access it from outside of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the lambda definition is in a method of the class the private field/property is defined in, no there isn't. You'll have to deal with reflection then.

Comment: "Unless you are inside the class" sounds like you are referring to the lambda invocation, not the lambda definition. Note Henk's answer below.

Answer (score 6):

No, unless (unlikely) the lambda is defined inside a method of the class of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this outside or inside of the class,  This is only working for fields right now but you can modify it for properties if you want.

```
public static Func<T, R> GetFieldAccessor<T, R>(string fieldName)
{
    ParameterExpression param =
    Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "arg");

    MemberExpression member =
    Expression.Field(param, fieldName);

    LambdaExpression lambda =
    Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<T, R>), member, param);

    Func<T, R> compiled = (Func<T, R>)lambda.Compile();
    return compiled;
}
```

usage would looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
     private int _secret = 10;
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
Console.WriteLine("func:" + GetFieldAccessor<MyClass, int>("_secret").Invoke(myClass));
```